# How to disable specific compilation warnings from CPP compiler in VSCode? (preferably using build options)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino-esp32

I am using VSCode and ESP-IDF to program Arduino. Some of the Arduino library files are generating warnings such as below.

```
988/1135] Building CXX object esp-idf/arduino/CMakeFiles/__idf_arduino.dir/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiScan.cpp.obj
/Users/sr/projects/gcp-iot/components/arduino/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiScan.cpp:45:21: warning: 'const char* cipher_str(int)' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static const char * cipher_str(int cipher)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
[1003/1135] Building CXX object esp-idf/arduino/CMakeFiles/__idf_arduino.dir/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiGeneric.cpp.obj
/Users/sr/projects/gcp-iot/components/arduino/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiGeneric.cpp:187:21: warning: 'const char* auth_mode_str(int)' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static const char * auth_mode_str(int authmode)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[1013/1135] Building CXX object esp-idf/arduino/CMakeFiles/__idf_arduino.dir/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.cpp.obj
/Users/sr/projects/gcp-iot/components/arduino/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.cpp: In member function 'uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint16_t, uint8_t, bool)':
/Users/sriraj/projects/gcp-iot/components/arduino/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.cpp:363:15: warning: variable 'err' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     esp_err_t err = ESP_OK;
```

I have tried setting `-Wno-unused-function` flag in various places but have failed to disable these warnings. Can someone please advise the right place to set this build option so I don't see these warnings. I am using VSCode on MacOS. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do NOT disable all warnings -- Bad idea. Find the warning you want to disable and disable that one only (e.g. unused functions). Warnings are an important part of what your compiler does to help you write better code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed - the question is how to disable just the unused functions warning. I'll change the title to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your `ESP-IDF` directory and look for `build.cmake` file under `esp-idf/tools/cmake` directory.

In the `build.cmake` file - look for the section called `function(__build_set_default_build_specifications)` - this contains all the default compiler options that are executed at build time. Include `-Wno-unused-function` here, save and recompile your project!

But be aware that this will disable this warning globally and affect other projects as well.

Comment: Alternative: surround the unused code with `#ifdef`, `#endif` and keep the warnings.